# Variable is initialized but appears to be null in onClick method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

```
public class PickUpFragment extends SherlockFragment implements OnMarkerDragListener, OnCameraChangeListener
{

    View rootView;

    private SupportMapFragment fragment;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private MySupportMapFragment itsMySupportMapFragment;

    RelativeLayout progress_rl;
    RelativeLayout map_rl;
    Button button;

    public LatLng latlng;
    TextView tv;
    public String address = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pickup, container, false);

    progress_rl= (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    map_rl = (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_container);
    //button.setOnClickListener(pickup);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    itsMySupportMapFragment = new MySupportMapFragment();
    MapViewCreatedListener mapViewCreatedListener = new MapViewCreatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapCreated() {
            initPlacesGoogleMapCtrl();
        }


    };
    itsMySupportMapFragment.itsMapViewCreatedListener = mapViewCreatedListener;
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.map, itsMySupportMapFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}

Marker marker;
Location loc;

public void initPlacesGoogleMapCtrl() {
    // Map ready, get it.
    map = itsMySupportMapFragment.getMap();
    // Do what you want...
    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSherlockActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider

                latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

                if(loc == null)
                {
                    loc = location;
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
                    //marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude())).draggable(true));

                    try {

                        tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_address);
                        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(PickUpFragment.this.getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                        List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                        if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
                            tv.setText("Waiting for Location");
                        }
                        else {
                            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                                String addr = "";
                                if(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() != null || addresses.get(0).getFeatureName().equals("null"))
                                {
                                    addr += addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                                }
                                if(addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null || addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare().equals("null") && !addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare().equals(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName()))
                                {
                                    addr += " " + addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
                                }
                                if(addresses.get(0).getLocality() != null || addresses.get(0).getLocality().equals("null"))
                                {
                                    addr += ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                }
                                address = addr + ", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                                tv.setText(address);
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Address:- " + addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + addresses.get(0).getLocality(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(); // getFromLocation() may sometimes fail
                    }

                }



            } 

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
          };

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}

public void pickup(View v, Activity act)
{
    Sync sync = new Sync();
    String ad = tv.getText().toString();
    sync.makeBooking(latlng, ad, getActivity());
    RelativeLayout progress_rl = (RelativeLayout)act.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    progress_rl.setVisibility(getView().VISIBLE);
    RelativeLayout map_rl = (RelativeLayout)act.findViewById(R.id.map_container);
    map_rl.setVisibility(getView().GONE);
    ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) progress_rl.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
    try
    {
        latlng = arg0.target;
        tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_address);
        Async async = new Async();
        async.execute();


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}

 private class Async extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
 {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try
        {

            Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(PickUpFragment.this.getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.isEmpty()) {

            }
            else {
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    String addr = "";
                    if(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() != null && !addresses.get(0).getFeatureName().equals("null"))
                    {
                        addr += addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                    }
                    if(addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null && !addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare().equals("null") && !addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare().equals(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName()))
                    {
                        addr += " " + addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
                    }
                    if(addresses.get(0).getLocality() != null && !addresses.get(0).getLocality().equals("null"))
                    {
                        addr += ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    }
                    address = addr + ", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Address:- " + addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + addresses.get(0).getLocality(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        tv.setText("Waiting for Location");
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        tv.setText(address);
    }



 }
}
```

The TextView tv is initialized the method initPlacesGoogleMapCtrl(). When I debug and step through line by line I can see that it was the correct value.

But when I try to use this value in pickup() it's null even though it was initialized earlier.

rootView and all the other class variables that are set throughout the running of the app are all null in the pickup method.

Any idea why it would be initialized and then suddenly it's null?

Comment: Are you *sure* that `initPlacesGoogleMapCtrl()` is called before `pickup()` and that nothing changes the value in between?

Comment: When I debug and step through, the break point in `initPlacesGoogleMapCtrl()` is called straight away but it's not until I press a button that `pickup()` is called.

Comment: It is also changed in onCameraChange(), which could cause it to become null between the two method calls.

Comment: In `onCameraChange()` tv always has the correct value and is never null. It is only in the `pickup()` method that the `NullPointerException` is thrown.